# jQuery formating universal currency data

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency

I'm trying to clear multiple currencies (like the US and EU) and round up. What I'm trying to do is;

```
10.30 → 10
10.60 → 11
849.95 → 850
1,022.20 → 1022
1.022,20 → 1022
230,20 → 230
30,20 → 30
```

I can do it if it's separated by a dot but the comma ones don't work https://jsfiddle.net/pmhgx7ut/

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/jq4d5tnv/ ?

Comment: It doesn't play nicely with 1,022.20

Comment: First replace the comma with a Dot

Comment: That's the Indian currency, ₹ 1,022.20 (or £) and this is US $1.022,20. Need to cover both.

Comment: Please include all relevant code on this site, not only on an external site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on what you already wrote, you can try the following:

```
var price = "1.022,20";

// comma and dot case
if (price.indexOf(',') < price.indexOf('.')) {
var price = price.replace(/[^0-9\.\,]/g, '');
var price = price.replace(",","");
};

// comma case
if (price.includes(",")==true && price.includes(".")==false)
{var price = price.replace(",",".");}

else //dot and comma case
{
if (price.indexOf('.') < price.indexOf(',')) {
var price = price.replace(",",".");
var price = price.replace(".",",");
var price = price.replace(/[^0-9\.\,]/g, '');
var price = price.replace(",","");};
};

var price = Math.round(price);
alert(price);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle some cases such as £600,30 or £200 both if which return NaN

Comment: 600,30 works if the £ symbol is removed. You can still use:var price = price.replace("£","");  if it is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```js
prices = [
 '£6,000.98',
 '£6.000,98',
 '£600.30',
 '£600,30',
 '£200',
];

prices.forEach(price => {
 // Check for a dot or comma followed by 2 digits at the end of price
 const cents_match = price.match(/[\,\.](\d{2})$/);

 // Check if we got a match and round the calue, or set cents to 0
 const cents = cents_match ? Math.round(cents_match[1] / 100) : 0;

 // Get the price without cents, add the rounded cents value.
 price = +(cents_match ? price.slice(0, price.length - 3) : price).replace(/\D/g, '') + cents;

 // Output
 console.log(price);
});
```